# Corrupt Superblock in /dev/sda

Tags: boot, partitioning, permissions, mount, grub2

I ran into grub rescue mode this morning and I tried to fix it with live USB, but after running `lilo -M /dev/sda mbr` when I boot with live usb again, I get these errors before booting successfully:

https://pasteboard.co/I9is2QB.jpg

Also, my /dev/sda is not accessible and partitions are not showing in `fdisk -l`:

`fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop4: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop5: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop6: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Permission denied`

Output of `sudo lsblk` is:

`NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   1.7G  1 loop /rofs
loop1    7:1    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
loop2    7:2    0   140M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop3    7:3    0   1.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop4    7:4    0  12.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop5    7:5    0    21M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop6    7:6    0   3.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
sdb      8:16   1  14.4G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14.4G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom`

And, output of `sudo fsck /dev/sda` is:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

There are 2 thigs at play here. Your hard drive is dead/dying as the pastebin errors and it looks like you did not execute the fdisk commands as root so they failed.